# Index Mysql database using Data Import Handler in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I want to index mysql database in solr using the Data Import Handler.

I have made two tables. The first table holds the metadata of a file.

```
create table filemetadata (
id varchar(20) primary key ,
filename varchar(50),
path varchar(200),
size varchar(10),
author varchar(50)
) ;

+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| id    | filename    | path    | size | author  | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| 1     | abc.txt     | c:\files| 2kb  | eric    | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| 2     | xyz.docx    | c:\files| 5kb  | john    | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| 3     | pqr.txt     |c:\files | 10kb | mike    | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
```

The second table contains the "favourite" info about a particular file in the above table.

```
create table filefav (
fid varchar(20) primary key ,
id varchar(20),
favouritedby varchar(300),
favouritedtime varchar(10),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES filemetadata(id) 
) ;

+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| fid    | id   | favouritedby    | favouritedtime | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 1      | 1    | ross            | 22:30          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 2      | 1    | josh            | 12:56          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 3      | 2    | johny           | 03:03          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 4      | 2    | sean            | 03:45          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
```

here "id' is a foreign key. The second table is showing which person has marked which document as his/her favourite. Eg the file abc.txt represented by id = 1 has been marked favourite (see column favouritedby) by ross and josh.

I want to index the the files as follows:

each document should have the following fields

```
id       - to be taken from the first table filemetadata
filename - to be taken from the first table filemetadata
path     - to be taken from the first table filemetadata
size     - to be taken from the first table filemetadata
author   - to be taken from the first table filemetadata
Favouritedby - this field should contain the names of all the people from table 2 filefav (from the favouritedby column) who like that particular file.
```

eg after indexing doc 1 should have

```
id = 1
filename = abc.txt
path = c:\files
size = 2kb
author = eric
favourited by - ross , josh
```

How Do I achieve this?

I have written a data-config.xml (which is not giving the desired result) as follows

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="root" /> 
<document name="filemetadata">

<entity name="restaurant" query="select * from filemetadata">
<field column="id" name="id" /> 

 <entity name="filefav" query="select favouritedby from filefav where id=${filemetadata.id}">
<field column="favouritedby" name="favouritedby1" />
</entity>

<field column="filename" name="name1" /> 
<field column="path" name="path1" /> 
<field column="size" name="size1" /> 
<field column="author" name="author1" />  

</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Can anyone explain how do i achieve this?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem you're seeing with the current results?

Comment: Instead of writing down 2 separate query you can do join and get all the result. after getting all the result mention those fields in schema.xml to make index and keep "id" in unique key.

Comment: I used a join and everything is working perfectly now. Thanks!